# How do I set up an old but Fancy CRT with Ubuntu?

Tags: display, display-resolution

My best monitor is still an old CRT, a SAMSUNG SyncMaster 900p, still working, will do resolutions up to 2048x1536 and 1920x1080 (yes it also does widescreen with a little fiddling) when hooked to a Windows PC.  But Ubuntu does not recognize the old monitor and only gives me two resolution options, 800x600 and 1024x768.  Samsung's website no longer has any drivers at all for CRT monitors.  Used to be to fix this kind of thing there was an X configuration file you edited, specified either a list of resolutions, or a range of refresh frequencies, and voila!  X would give you all the choices!  But it's been a long time since I did that, can't seem to find that file or whether it even exists anymore.  Does it?  If it doesn't, is there still a way to tell Ubuntu what monitor it's dealing with?

Comment: Typing lines like this for each mode I wanted to add into an xterm window seems to have worked, but it seems kinda hacky to me (and old, occasionally they returned an error) , so if anyone knows a way to get Ubuntu to actually detect my Samsung CRT, let me know.

`xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1280 1024 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1280x1024/')`
`xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024`

Comment: And in fact that solution doesn't seem to stick.  Next time I rebooted the machine the settings were back to being wrong again and I had to type all those commands again. :(  Anyone know how to make them permanent or better yet the RIGHT way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: There's an app like that already. Look up cool retro term. If you want i can write an answer with steps to installing it

Answer (score 2):

I'll just copy-paste one of my previous answers here:

This is such a common problem... * sigh *

The easiest thing to do is add that resolution using `xrandr` - [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html) is a good guide. You would then need to add the `xrandr` configurations to a startup file, so that you'll get your desired resolution upon reboot/startup.

You can do all this hassle-free using a simple program; [ResolutionX](http://www.sourceforge.com/p/resolutionx) - it is a graphical front-end to `randr`, so if `xrandr` works for you, so will that.

Comment: The ResolutionX link doesn't appear to be working